# passing value from Knockoutjs dropdownlist to SQL MVC5

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, knockout.js

Ok so I have Kocokout array that is populating a dropdownlist

```
var idDDL = (from c in db.IDLists select new ID { ID = c.ID, ID = c.ID}).ToArray();

var IDList = Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.idDDL));
```

I have a form with submit button

the drop downs bind to the select.

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 0px">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="idDDL" data-bind="options: list, optionsText: 'ID'"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create" />
```

on the count/register controller I have added these to the register model and added them to the new ApplicationUser()

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, ClubType = model.ClubType, UserAuthorityLevel = model.AuthType, ClubID = model.ClubID };
```

and my registerviewmodel had these added to it

```
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type ")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Authority Level ")]
    public string AuthType { get; set; }
```

I know i am missing something that's maybe simple any help would be welcome, PS sorry for my poor English skills

Answer (score 0):

Use [optionsValue](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) to bind to selected item:

```
<select id="idDDL" data-bind="options: list, optionsText: 'ID', optionsValue: 'SelectedID'"></select>
```